# Geometry - Pentagon

Tags: geometry

This is a tough program I have hard time to find the answer. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much in advance.

Problem - In regular pentagon $ABCDE$, point $M$ is the midpoint of side $AE$, and segments $AC$ and $BM$ intersect at point $Z$. If $ZA = 3$, what is the value of $AB$? Express your answer in simplest radical form.

This is a drawing for the problem:

[image]

Comment: An illustration would be extremely useful here (and would also prove some effort on your side, which this question currently lacks evidence of).

Comment: How do I add a drawing after posting the problem? I'm new here. Thank you.

Comment: Click `edit`, and then click the `image` icon at the top of your post.

Comment: I wonder whether there is a simple to solve the problem. This is a middle school problem.

Comment: A nice solution can be found from this address: https://www.mathcounts.org/sites/default/files/u5328/2015%20State%20Competition%20Solutions%20-%20FINAL.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Choose the coordinate system so that $A = (0,0)$, $B = (\rho,0)$ and the other three vertices lie in the upper half plane. Identify the plane with complex numbers, the
five sides of the pentagon corresponds to
$$( AB, BC, CD, DE, EA ) \quad\leftrightarrow\quad (\rho,\rho\omega,\rho\omega^2,\rho\omega^3,\rho\omega^4)$$
where $\omega = e^{2\pi i/5}$ is the primitive $5^{th}$ root of unity.

Under this identification,

$$B = AB = \rho,\; C = AB+BC = \rho(1 + \omega)
\quad\text{ and }\quad
M = -\frac12 EA = -\frac{\rho}{2} \omega^4 = -\frac{\rho}{2} \bar{\omega}$$

Since $Z$ lies on the intersection of $AC$ and $BM$, there exists real numbers $\lambda, \mu$ such that
$$AZ = \lambda AC = (1-\mu) AB + \mu AM$$
This impies
$$\frac{Z}{\rho} = \lambda( 1 + \omega) = (1-\mu) - \mu\frac{\bar{\omega}}{2}
= \left[1 - \mu \left( 1 + \frac{\omega + \bar{\omega}}{2} \right)\right] + \frac{\mu}{2}\omega
$$
The square bracket in RHS is clearly a real number. By comparing the real
and imaginary part of the last equality, we get:

$$\lambda = 1 - \mu\left(1 + \frac{\omega + \bar{\omega}}{2} \right) = \frac{\mu}{2}
\implies \lambda = \frac{1}{3 + \omega + \bar{\omega}}
$$

This implies

$$|AB| = \rho
= \left|\frac{AZ}{\lambda(1 + \omega)}\right| 
= 3 \left|\frac{3+\omega+\bar{\omega}}{1+\omega}\right|
= 3\left(\frac{3 + 2\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}}{2\cos\frac{\pi}{5}}\right)
= 3\left(\frac{2+\phi}{\phi}\right) = 3\sqrt{5}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, Achille. I wonder whether there is a simple to solve the problem. This is a middle school problem.

Comment: @teamember all the steps above can be rephrased in turns of vectors. The proof will be more ugly than this but it is doable by middle schoolers. There should be more ingenious way to get the answer but I haven't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 4):

Let $F$ be the intersection of $AC$ and $BE$. By angle chasing, we obtain the following picture:

[image]

Now $\triangle BAF$ and $\triangle BEA$ are similar, so 
$$BF:BA = BA:BE,$$
or 
$$\frac yx = \frac{x}{x+y}=\frac{1}{1+y/x}.\tag{1}$$
Solving that for $y$ in terms of $x$ we have 
$$\frac yx = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}2.$$

Now apply [Menelaus' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27_theorem) to $\triangle AEF$ with $M$, $Z$, $B$ colinear we get
$$\frac{EM}{MA}\cdot \frac{ZA}{ZF}\cdot \frac{BF}{BE} = 1.\tag{2}$$
Note that $EM = MA$,
$$\frac{BF}{BE} = \frac{y}{x+y}=1-\frac{x}{x+y}=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}2,$$
and
$$\frac{ZA}{ZF} = \frac{3}{y-3}.$$
Thus, (2) becomes
$$\frac{y-3}{3} = \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}2.$$
So
$$ y = \frac{9-3\sqrt{5}}{2}+3 = \frac{15-3\sqrt{5}}2.$$
And we get 
$$ x = \frac xy \cdot y = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}2 \cdot \frac{15-3\sqrt{5}}2$$

---

Note:

1. I'm sure there are more elegant solutions.
2. One can avoid Menelaus' Theorem by connecting $M$ with the midpoint $N$ of $AF$.

Comment: +1 your solution is at least more elegant than mine and the one in the link from OP. BTW, your last expression can be simplified to $3\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: @achillehui I knew that from your answer :-).